# How to assign value to the slice of structure

Tags: go, structure

I am using table driven test for my method but getting error while assigning the value to the field which is the array of structure, situation is something like given below.

```
var validStats = []struct{
    status       []v1.ReplicaStatus
}{
   {
     status: []v1.ReplicaStatus {
             IP              string
             Status          string
             DataUpdateIndex string
    }{
       {
           IP:              "10.10.10.10",
           Status:          "Online",
           DataUpdateIndex: "1",
       },
       {
           IP:              "10.10.10.11",
           Status:          "Online",
           DataUpdateIndex: "1",
       },
     },
   }
}
```

and I'm getting the error `missing ',' in composite literal` at line no 6 and at the end of the code.What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a named type (`ReplicaStatus`), but then trying to define your struct fields anyway:

```
 status: []v1.ReplicaStatus {
         IP              string
         Status          string
         DataUpdateIndex string
}{
```

Don't do that. Instead, do this:

```
 status: []v1.ReplicaStatus{
   {
       IP:              "10.10.10.10",
       Status:          "Online",
       DataUpdateIndex: "1",
   },
   {
       IP:              "10.10.10.11",
       Status:          "Online",
       DataUpdateIndex: "1",
   },
 }
```

You should only define field names in this context, if you are using an unnamed type, as in:

```
status := []struct { // Notice this is now an anonymous struct type
         IP              string
         Status          string
         DataUpdateIndex string
}{
   {
       IP:              "10.10.10.10",
       Status:          "Online",
       DataUpdateIndex: "1",
   },
   {
       IP:              "10.10.10.11",
       Status:          "Online",
       DataUpdateIndex: "1",
   },
 }
```

Comment: @UtkarshManiTripathi: Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: @Filmzy i don't have 15 reputation yet to upvote your answer :(